Is there a way to add a notch above the center icon in BottomNavigationBar(Flutter)? Something like in this image:
           return BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              fixedColor: Color(0xff2398C3),
              showSelectedLabels: false,
              showUnselectedLabels: false,
              currentIndex: snapshot.data.index,
              onTap: _bottomNavBarBloc.pickItem,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  title: Text('Search'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  title: Text('Browse'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.view_list),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  title: Text('Icon'),
                  icon: Container(
                    child: FlutterLogo(
                      size: 35.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  title: Text('Favorites'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  title: Text('Settings'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                ),
              ],
            );



You can using custom painter
Sample:
///
///Scaffold(
///  bottomNavigationBar: const Bn30(),
///);

class Bn30 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Bn30({super.key});

  @override
  State<Bn30> createState() => _Bn30State();
}

class _Bn30State extends State<Bn30> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: Bn30Painter(),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: const [
              Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.access_time_filled,size: 30)),
              Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.access_time_filled,size: 30)),
              Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.access_time_filled, size: 60)),
              Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.access_time_filled,size: 30)),
              Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.access_time_filled,size: 30)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Bn30Painter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    const ratio = 2.6;
    final controllPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, -30);
    final subControllPoint = Offset(size.width - size.width / ratio, 3);

    final paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..strokeJoin
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width / ratio - 10, 5);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / ratio, 3, size.width / ratio +10, -3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(controllPoint.dx, controllPoint.dy, size.width - size.width / ratio -10, -3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(subControllPoint.dx, subControllPoint.dy, size.width - size.width / ratio +10, 3);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    final Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    const Gradient gradient = LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Colors.white,
        Colors.white,
        Colors.blue,
        Colors.white,
        Colors.white,
      ],
      stops: [0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0],
      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
      end: Alignment.centerRight,
    );

    final Paint paint2 = Paint()
      ..shader = gradient.createShader(rect)
      ..strokeWidth = 3
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    
    
    final path2 = Path();
    path2.moveTo(0, 1);
    path2.lineTo(size.width / ratio -10, 5);
    path2.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / ratio, 3, size.width / ratio +10, -3);
    path2.quadraticBezierTo(controllPoint.dx, controllPoint.dy, size.width - size.width / ratio -10, -3);
    path2.quadraticBezierTo(subControllPoint.dx, subControllPoint.dy, size.width - size.width / ratio +10, 3);
    path2.lineTo(size.width, 1);
    canvas.drawPath(path2, paint2);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}


Thank you so much for your assistance, it is indeed functioning perfectly.
